# How can I get an Android MediaController to appear from layout xml?

Tags: android

I've created a layout.xml file with the following XML, but I can't get the MediaController to appear at all.

```
<MediaController android:id="@+id/media_controller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

In code, I can obtain a reference to it from code, call show(), etc, but it never appears.

I have noticed in the android dev documentation ([MediaController.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html)) that it states, "The way to use this class is to instantiate it programatically.", so maybe I'm a dufus and just need to do something differently such as not do what I'm doing.  :)

I CAN get it to appear if I do it programmatically, but I need it to always appear on the screen.  Am I just being stupid, or is it just not meant to be inflated via XML?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [this sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Media/Video/):

```
ctlr=new MediaController(this);
ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
video.setMediaController(ctlr);
```

Then, it will appear when you tap the screen towards the bottom edge of your `VideoView`.

In terms of keeping it on screen all the time...I don't know if that's possible. You can always create your own controller -- [here's a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry) that creates its own pop-up translucent controller. It's really not all that hard, and you get full control over everything, including arranging for it to be on-screen all the time.

Comment: ctlr.show(0) does show the controller until hide is called sir

Answer (score 10):

You can prevent the MediaController from hiding extending MediaController and override hide() to do nothing. eg:

```
class UnhideableMediaController extends MediaController
{
    // override whichever contstructors you need to. 
    public UnhideableMediaController(Context context)
    {
      super(context);
    }

    // override hide to do nothing
    public void hide()
    {
      // don't hide
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By using show(0) **media controller** will be shown until hide() is called by an interaction with the player. I found unfortunately no way to prevent hide() yet;-(

```
MediaController mc = new MediaController(MPlayer.this);  
 mc.setMediaPlayer(MPlayer.this);  
 mc.setEnabled(true);

 View mMediaControllerView = (View)findViewById(R.id.media_controller); //get it from your layout

 mc.setAnchorView(mMediaControllerView);
 mMediaControllerView.setOnTouchListener(mPlayerTouchListener);//also use show() in onTouchListener

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
        mc.show(0);
     } }, 1500);
```

Wait for screen to buid in order to avoid a bug in android (1,5 seconds here)

Answer (score 2):

You can inflate a mediacontroller from the layout xml. Also after obtaining a reference of it can set a videoview as an anchor.

- **But this will cause a crash as soon as you try to touch
  mediacontroller (I am trying to figure out why its happening).**

Also In this mediaController will appear always.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/mVideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <MediaController
        android:id="@+id/mediaController1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In activity,

```
public class AnimationActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private MediaController mController = null;
    private VideoView mVideoView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation);
        mController = (MediaController) findViewById(R.id.mediaController1);
        mController.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.mVideoView);
                mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                        + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video0));
                mController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
                mVideoView.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
                mVideoView.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.docstoc.com/docs/9811647/Media-on-the-Android-Platform

This doc suggests you may need to extend the Controller to get the behaviour that you need.

You could also show it for a very long time i suppose ;)

I'm presently struggling to even get the controller to show then I press a button :\

(also interesting how quickly google added this question to search results)

Answer (score 0):

When declaring my MediaController in a layout file, getting a handle on it in code (using the `Activity.findViewById(int id)` method) and attaching it to my VideoView (using the `VideoView.setMediaController(MediaController controller)` method), I find it behaves undesirably (force closes the app) at times. Instead, I create it in code, attach it to the VideoView and then specify where it should display in the Activity using the `VideoView.setAnchorView(View view)` method as follows:

```
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(myVideoUrl));
myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
{
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
  {
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(MyActivity.this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    // put the MediaController at the bottom of the Activity rather than directly beneath the VideoView
    // (note that my Activity's layout file has root node with id 'myactivity_layoutroot')
    if (findViewById(R.id.myactivity_layoutroot) != null)
      mediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.myactivity_layoutroot));

    videoView.requestFocus();
  }
});
myVideoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is your "mVideoView.setVideoURI" section. I have recently been working on a similar thing including this and it seems that the video has to be retrieved via server. You will need to store your videos on a server then call it here. That's what happened with me anyway.