# Play video with media controller on specific area of an activity

Tags: android, media, tablet, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, mediacontroller

[image: a busy cat]

I want to make layout like the attached image but the problem is when I create media controller it doesn't appear below the video player instead it shows on the centre bottom of activity. I've tried to make mediacontroller in xml file but It doesn't work either and also tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10315093/1065357 but it also doesn't work.
I am using android 4 tablet version.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your custom media control panel, use a bottom panel, add buttons of play,pause,stop etc. add that bottom panel layout where you you want by using `layout gravity`. On the click on your custom play,pause, stop, forward etc buttons you can call `mediaPlayer.play()`, `mediaPlayer.pause()`  etc.

for this purpose, you will be needing to implement `SurfaceHolder.callback`   interface as follow:

```
public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{

public boolean canPause() 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.e("paused ","called");
    return true;
}


public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}


public boolean canSeekForward() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}


public int getBufferPercentage()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stu
    return 0;
}


public int getCurrentPosition() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();


}


public int getDuration() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
}


public boolean isPlaying() 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying(); 
}


public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mMediaPlayer.pause();
}


public void seekTo(int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);

}


public void start()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

}

implementation of this interface will give you access to the media controlling functions(play,pause,seek etc).

Surface holder can be get as   `SurfaceHolder holder= surfaceView.getHolder();` and then `mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder)`

you would be declaring your surfaceView tag in your  videoViewActivity's layout.
surface holder is the component that would be display the video stream of your video.

i hope this will help.