# Customizing MediaController

Tags: android, themes, customization, android-theme, mediacontroller

I'm looking for a simple and stable way to change the images of the `MediaController` control. My research is so far that I looked at the source codes of the [MediaController](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.1_r1/core/java/android/widget/MediaController.java) and its [layout file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.1_r1/core/res/res/layout/media_controller.xml) and also a copy of [com.android.internal.R](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/constant-values.html#com.android.internal.R.id.pause) for figgering out the correct ids. But I'm not sure if this is a good way to use the fixed ids form that page. I'm not sure if the I should use the ids, because they may change thrue the differnt SDK versions. **The ids can change isn't it?**

So far I thought to use another solution where I walk down the elements of the MediaController like explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12718302/995926). This may work but could make trouble if the control is changed in future releases **or is this save to use?**

My newest idea is to uses Themes, but I'm not sure if it is simple to replace the style because the controls uses `style="@android:style/MediaButton.Xxx"` which is another namespace/package. **So is theming an option to change the layout?**

Comment: I think,yes changing theme would be an option of what you want..

Comment: Could you add a small example for one button? I'm not sure if I understood the structure corectly.

Comment: See..http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e2be250424fad51f http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759862/how-can-i-get-an-android-mediacontroller-to-appear-from-layout-xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044000/change-style-of-android-mediacontroller

Comment: Here is an example MediaController customization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482203/how-to-create-custom-ui-for-android-mediacontroller/14323144#14323144

Comment: I'll have a look to that tomorrow right now I'm a little sceptic how you override the images dynamically. That was my main problem.